# Multithreading actively waiting

Tags: java, multithreading

I'm working on a problem where I have to use 4 different threads to write out a LETTER event INTERNAL ms AMOUNT times. The first 3 threads start right away the forth one is awaiting for one of them to finish & then starting.

I have got the code to a point where is doing what it should although the code is not "ending" it's actively waiting.

Could you advise what could be the issue here?

```
public class PrinterThread extends Thread {

    private String letter;
    private int internal;
    private int amount;


    public PrinterThread(String letter, int internal, int amount){
        this.letter = letter;
        this.internal = internal;
        this.amount = amount;
    }

    public void run(){
        for (int i = 1; i <= amount; i++) {
            System.out.println(letter);
            try {
                Thread.sleep(internal);
            } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }

    }
}

    public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {


        PrinterThread printerThread = new PrinterThread("A", 1, 1000);
        PrinterThread printerThread1 = new PrinterThread("B", 1, 1000);
        PrinterThread printerThread2 = new PrinterThread("C", 1, 1);
        PrinterThread printerThread3 = new PrinterThread("D", 5, 50);

        printerThread.start();
        printerThread1.start();
        printerThread2.start();

        while(!printerThread3.isAlive()){
            if (!printerThread.isAlive() || !printerThread1.isAlive() || !printerThread2.isAlive()) {
                printerThread3.start();
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Re, "the code is not "ending" it's activley waiting." Can you explain the problem in more detail? When I run your code, the program does exactly what I would expect,\* and then it ends. [\*I expect it to print 1000 lines of "A", 1000 lines of "B", 1 line of "C", and 50 lines of "D" in no particular order.]

Answer (score 1):

Break out of the while loop, once you have started printerThread3.

```
public class PrinterThread extends Thread {

    private String letter;
    private int internal;
    private int amount;


    public PrinterThread(String letter, int internal, int amount){
        this.letter = letter;
        this.internal = internal;
        this.amount = amount;
    }

    public void run(){
        for (int i = 1; i <= amount; i++) {
            System.out.println(letter);
            try {
                Thread.sleep(internal);
            } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }

    }
}

    public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {


        PrinterThread printerThread = new PrinterThread("A", 1, 1000);
        PrinterThread printerThread1 = new PrinterThread("B", 1, 1000);
        PrinterThread printerThread2 = new PrinterThread("C", 1, 1);
        PrinterThread printerThread3 = new PrinterThread("D", 5, 50);

        printerThread.start();
        printerThread1.start();
        printerThread2.start();

        while(!printerThread3.isAlive()){
            if (!printerThread.isAlive() || !printerThread1.isAlive() || !printerThread2.isAlive()) {
                printerThread3.start();
                break;
            }
        }
        
        //If you want main to wait for all the others to complete, then add this...
        printerThread.join();
        printerThread1.join();
        printerThread2.join();
        printerThread3.join();
    }
}
```

Comment: Kind of... Main thread stays in the While loop endlessly.

Comment: Although, Thread.start documentation says it should throw an exception when called on an already started Thread. So, I am not sure how OP didn't mention any exception.

Comment: What would you say the best line attack would be to break out the while loop ?

Comment: Just start that `printerThread3` and then `break` the while loop. If you want `main` to wait for all threads to complete, put a `join` for each of them. I added the updated code.